# Is it possible to access a "stored date" (metadata) of a localstorage item?

Tags: javascript, html, web-storage

I am working on a web app where I use localstorage to store in-progress data for incomplete activities. I would like to display when last an incomplete activity was updated. It would be possible to add a "storedDate" (or similar) field to the items I store and update it whenever the data is updated, but I would rather use a "stored date" meta (if there is any available) for a more generic approach.

I have looked at all the HTML5 web storage API references that I could find, but have not been able to find any relating to metadata available on localstorage items (if any). Is anything available? Does anyone have documentation I could look at to access the metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local Storage is a simple key-value storage, where is the "value" is always a string. 
You can store a JSON object, but you have to stringify it.

Example:

```
var objToStore = {
  my_date: Date.now(),
  any_data: "SUPER TEXT"
};

localStorage['my_value'] = JSON.stringify(objToStore);
```

If you need to read and parse it:

```
var readValue;
try {
  readValue = JSON.parse(localStorage['my_value'])
} catch(e) {
  // parse error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Deliaz. However, my question is actually whether any metadata gets stored about a localstorage item, and if one is able to retrieve the metadata (for example, is it possible to get the date of when a specific localstorage item was set, without saving a date field on the item?)

Comment: @nonorval there is no such data. Unless you set it manually, as I demonstrated.